# JPA with local resource instead of JTA datasource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am building a simple web application for which I would like to use JPA.  Although I expect to be deploying on Glassfish I was think that it may be beneficial to manage entity persistence within the application rather than through JTA datasource. I acknowledge that this may not be a very bright idea?

Some time ago I put the following together (possibly from a now lost web reference):

```
public class PersistenceManager {
    private static final PersistenceManager instance = new PersistenceManager();
    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public static PersistenceManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private PersistenceManager() {
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (emf == null) {
            createEntityManagerFactory();
        }
        return emf;
    }

    public void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (emf != null) {
            emf.close();
            emf = null;
        }
    }

    protected void createEntityManagerFactory() {
        this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Met");
    }
}
```

So, my questions;  Is this a reasonable approach - are there any pitfalls here?

Comment: I guess that I was thinking about possible deployment in a Servlet Container that does not support managed persistence.

Comment: Why would you like to take over transaction management? Your JPA code would be one and all a mess. Instead of just a `@PersistenceContext EntityManager em;` in an EJB and invoking oneliner methods on it, you've to manually create the entity manager factory, manually create the entity manager, manually start the transaction, manually commit the transaction, manually end the transaction, manually close the entity manager and manually close the entity manager factory. So, to reiterate Rick, how's that beneficial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always deployed JPA without container managed persistence. I've even used it with Atomikos JTA transaction manager. The simplest way is to not use JNDI based lookup. I would recomment using Spring's JPATransactionManager and to configure everything either with persistence.xml or spring-xml.

Persistence manager in Spring-xml:

```
<bean id="pum" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:META-INF/etf-persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="my-pu" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile">my-hibernate.cfg.xml</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.session_factory_name">mySessionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">none</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>       
    </property>
</bean>
```

Don't specify non-jta or jta-data-source tags in persistence.xml. The rest of the setup is standard-spring (EntityManagerFactory, DataSource etc.).

Comment: I'll update with sample xml when I get to my computer with a working example.

Comment: Why going for legacy Spring if Java EE already offers EJB and JTA out the box?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed not the best idea. As @BalusC pointed out you would need to take over all your own TX management plumbing, manually create and start and end everything. Its a ton of boilerplate code which opens you up to bugs and you get no benefit from it.

You can use JTA even if you are in a stripped down servlet container that does not provide it by adding it yourself, though you should have a very strong reason for wanting to assemble the stack yourself instead of just grabbing a AS like Glassfish which gives it all to you for free.

For that matter you can still use it even if you select the Glassfish web profile (vs the full platform).